# Android: Stop sound files playing at once

Tags: android, file, audio, media-player

In the application I am currently writing, a user is able to select an entry from the database and play the contents of that entry: an entry is made up of a number of sound files (without a limit). In my application, I return the URI locations of the sound files of an entry (which have been stored in my database) in a List. The code is as follows:

```
public void audioPlayer() {
    // set up MediaPlayer
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    Entry retrieveEntry = new Entry();

    retrieveEntry = db.getEntry();

    List<String> path = retrieveEntry.getAudioUri();

    path.size();

    System.out.println("PATH SIZE: " +path.size());

    System.out.println("FILEZ: " + path);

    Iterator<String> i = path.iterator();
    String myAudio;
    int count = 0;

    while (i.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(count);
            myAudio = i.next();
            System.out.println("MY AUDIO: " + myAudio);

            MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(myAudio));
            player.start();
            player.stop();
            player = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(myAudio));
            player.start();

            count++;
        }
}
```

My users require that there be user input for playing a file - is there a way to play the first file, then wait for the user to press the button, then play the second file, then wait for the user to press the button, etc.? At the moment, when the play button is pressed, all of the sound files that have been returned get played at the same time, rather than one after the other.

Thanks in advance for any help provided!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this class to play a playlist. This will start one audio, when that audio finishes, it will start playing next audio till the end of the list. If you want to play the playlist in looping i.e start first audio after reaching end, then pass isLooping=true in `startPlayingPlaylist(list,looping)`

```
    AudioPlayer player = new AudioPlayer();
    player.startPlayingPlaylist(list, false);
```

Class

```
public class AudioPlayer{
    MediaPlayer player = null;
    ArrayList<String> playlist = null;
    int position = 0;

    public AudioPlayer() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public void startPlayingPlaylist(ArrayList<String> list, boolean looping){
        playlist = list;
        if(player!=null){
            player.release();
        }
        if(playlist!=null && playlist.size()>0){
            player = MediaPlayer.create(LMApplicaton.getInstance(),Uri.parse(playlist.get(position)));
            player.setWakeMode(LMApplicaton.getInstance(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
            player.setLooping(looping);
            player.start();
            // Set onCompletion listener
            player.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    position = position+1;
                    if(position<playlist.size()){
                        try {
                            player.reset();
                            player.setDataSource(playlist.get(position));
                            player.prepareAsync();
                        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    } else if(player.isLooping()==true){
                        position = position%playlist.size();
                        try {
                            player.reset();
                            player.setDataSource(playlist.get(position));
                            player.prepareAsync();
                        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    else if(player.isLooping()==false){
                        player.release();
                        player = null;
                    }
                }
            });
            player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    player.start();
                }
            });
        }
    }
    public void pause(){
        if(player!=null && player.isPlaying()){
            player.pause();
        }
    }
    public void play(){
        if(player!=null && player.isPlaying()==false){
            player.start();
        }
    }
    public boolean isPlaying(){
        return player.isPlaying();
    }
    public void release(){
        if(player!=null){
            player.release();
        }
    }

}
```

**Edit:**
The class below receives a list of audios, then plays first Audio. It plays next audio when user calls `startNextAudio()` You can use any one of these according to your requirements

public class AudioPlayer{
    MediaPlayer player = null;
    ArrayList playlist = null;
    int position = 0;

```
public AudioPlayer() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public void startPlayingPlaylist(ArrayList<String> list){
    playlist = list;
    if(player!=null){
        player.release();
    }
    if(playlist!=null && playlist.size()>0){
        player = MediaPlayer.create(LMApplicaton.getInstance(),Uri.parse(playlist.get(position)));
        player.setWakeMode(LMApplicaton.getInstance(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
        player.start();
        // Set onCompletion listener
        player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                player.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
public void startNextAudio(){
    position = position+1;
    if(position<playlist.size()){
        try {
            player.reset();
            player.setDataSource(playlist.get(position));
            player.prepareAsync();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } else if(player.isLooping()==true){
        position = position%playlist.size();
        try {
            player.reset();
            player.setDataSource(playlist.get(position));
            player.prepareAsync();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else{
        Log.i("AudioPlayer","Playlist reached at the end");
    }
}
public void pause(){
    if(player!=null && player.isPlaying()){
        player.pause();
    }
}
public void play(){
    if(player!=null && player.isPlaying()==false){
        player.start();
    }
}
public boolean isPlaying(){
    return player.isPlaying();
}
public void release(){
    if(player!=null){
        player.release();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to implement the MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener interface. This gives you the MediaPlayer.onCompletion() callback method which you could use like so:

```
@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
  if (i.hasNext) {
    // ...hand mp the next file
    // ...show the user the 'play next' button
  }
}
```

Note you also will need to call the `MediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener()` method in your setup.